# Server error in application '/'. HTTP 404. MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am trying to show a view through the **`POST`** action method, but when calling this action it shows me the message **`"Server error in application '/'"`**.

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) may have been removed, renamed, or temporarily unavailable. Please review the URL below and make sure it is spelled correctly.
```

I have already created my respective view for this method using the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()`.

```
     [Route("Home/AddPiloto")]
     [Route("AddPiloto")]
     public ActionResult AddPiloto()
     {
         return View();
     }
```

Here is the **`POST`** action that I am calling from my html form, the method works and gets the data, `only the view fails.`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPiloto(PilotoClass pclass)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/AeronauticaDGAC/");
        var request = httpClient.PostAsync("webresources/conndatabase.piloto/supCreatePost", pclass,
            new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
        if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resultString = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var succes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(resultString);
            ViewBag.Mg = succes;
            return RedirectToAction("AddPiloto");
        }
        ViewBag.Mg = request.StatusCode;
        return RedirectToAction("Index",ViewBag);
    }
```

Finally here I have a typical form that calls this method **`POST`**.

```
        <form action="AddPiloto" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="id" value="" placeholder="Id" />
                <input id="inp1" class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nombre" />
                <input id="inp1" class="form-control" type="text" name="apellido" value="" placeholder="Apellido" />
                <input id="inp1" class="form-control" type="number" name="edad" value="" placeholder="Edad" />
                <hr />
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button" value="Enviar" />
                <input onclick="limpiarFormulario1()" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="button" value="Limpiar" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

I already have the view created, `compile` and `recompile` the solution, `clear the browser cache`, `check if the file exists` and `restart the IIS server`, but nothing works for me, if someone knows any possible solution I would greatly appreciate the answer.
Thanks in advance.

**`All code.`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using AeronauticaClient.Models;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;

namespace AeronauticaClient.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("Home")]
    [Route("{action}")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("~/")]
        [Route("")]
        [Route("Index")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient CHttp = new HttpClient();
            CHttp.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/AeronauticaDGAC/");
            var request = CHttp.GetAsync("webresources/conndatabase.piloto/supFindAllGet").Result;
            if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var resultString = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var listado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PilotoClass>>(resultString);
                ViewBag.Message = request;
                return View(listado);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = request;
            }
            return View();
        }
        
        [Route("Home/AddPiloto")]
        [Route("AddPiloto")]
        public ActionResult AddPiloto()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddPiloto(PilotoClass pclass)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/AeronauticaDGAC/");
            var request = httpClient.PostAsync("webresources/conndatabase.piloto/supCreatePost", pclass,
                new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;
            if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var resultString = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var succes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(resultString);
                ViewBag.Mg = succes;
                return RedirectToAction("AddPiloto");
            }
            ViewBag.Mg = request.StatusCode;
            return RedirectToAction("Index",ViewBag);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Routing code.`**

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you using two Route for the Action method?

Comment: Show code where you are sending request to controller

Comment: It should not affect the search of the view, it is the same route. It is in the same controller.

Comment: there I added all the controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect to index, you're passing `ViewBag` as an argument.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index",ViewBag);
```

But the server cannot find an index method receiving that parameter, so it raises an exception.

1. Remove `ViewBag` as an argument when you redirect.

   ```
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
   ```
2. Before redirecting, replace `ViewBag` for `TempData`

   ```
    if (request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var resultString = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var succes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(resultString);
        TempData["Mg"] = succes;
        return RedirectToAction("AddPiloto");
    }
    TempData["Mg"] = request.StatusCode;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
   ```
3. To retrieve the value you stored in previous step, use `TempData["Mg"]` further on.

You need `TempData` instead because after `RedirectToAction` you'll be in a new request. Since `ViewBag` is only available for same request, the values would be lost after redirecting.

Comment: The view is shown but now the problem is the URL, According to `[RoutePrefix ("Home")]` and `[Route ("Home / AddPiloto")]` or `[Route ("AddPiloto")]` the URL should be `http: // localhost: 57796 / Home / Addpilot`
but just let me see it with `http: // localhost: 57796 / Home / Home / Addpilot`,double **`HOME`**, is the route wrong?

Comment: I edited the post and added the routing code at the end, Thanks.

Comment: Your `RouteConfig` class should do the job, including pointing Home as default controller and Index as default action. I don't see what's the point for having all those `Route` and `RoutePrefix` in your controller class.

Comment: Try removing `[RoutePrefix("Home")]` from your HomeController class. This might be adding the extra "Home" to the Url.

Comment: For some reason I had to add the controller name to the action="controller/action" of the form and remove the routing. Thanks!